# NodeJS: Module did not self-register

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying IBM Watson's `Speech to Text` API. While running my NodeJS app I get this.

I am using line-in package for streaming the input audio data in output, in addition to IBM Watson's SpeechToText package.

I tried removing `node_modules` and `$ npm install` and `$ npm rebuild`. Nothing worked.

````
node app.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: Module did not self-register.
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:718:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Topgear\SpeechToText\node_modules\line-in\index.js:2:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)```

package.json
{
  "name": "SpeechToText",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "line-in": "^0.1.2",
    "watson-developer-cloud": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Nikhilesh AS",
  "license": "ISC"
}
````

Comment: try `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm install` , I'm not 100% sure if this works , but you can give it a try

Comment: I tried, nothing worked.

Comment: Is there any output when you run `npm rebuild line-in`? Do you have anything in ~/.npmrc or ./.npmrc that isn’t credentials?

Comment: Seems `watson-developer-cloud` package is deprecated, Try to use `ibm-watson` package

Comment: @Ry- I haven't logged in node. ./.npmrc is empty

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Is `SpeechToText` API the same as in `watson-developer-cloud` package or do I need to refactor my code to make it work?

Comment: `ibm-watson` latest version of `watson-developer-cloud` you better to use latest one to avoid such issues check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-watson for `Speech to Text` snippet

Comment: Clear NPM Cache: Clear the npm cache by running the following command: `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 0):

Checkout https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#worker-threads.

> On some platforms, including glibc-based Linux, the main thread must call require("module") from the main thread before worker threads are created. This is to ensure shared libraries remain loaded in memory until after all threads are complete.

You need to require module from main thread before worker threads are created.